# How do I target a specific .NET project within a Solution using MSBuild from VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, parallel-processing

I have an MSBuild command line that can build an entire solution. It looks something like this:

*msbuild SomeSolution.sln /p:Configuration:CustomDebug;Platform=OurPlatform /nodeReuse:false /maxcpucount:4 /t:Build*

I know that for C++ Solutions, specific projects can be targeted using the following syntax:

*msbuild SomeSolution.sln /p:Configuration:CustomDebug;Platform=OurPlatform /nodeReuse:false /maxcpucount:4 **/t:Folder\SomeCppProject;Build***

I'm trying to achieve the same thing for .NET projects within a solution. This does NOT work:

*msbuild SomeSolution.sln /p:Configuration:CustomDebug;Platform=OurPlatform /nodeReuse:false /maxcpucount:4 **/t:SomeDotNetProject;Build***

Does anyone know how to target a specific project within a solution using MSBuild on the command line for .NET projects? I know I can create a custom MSBuild project to achieve what I'm after, but I need to share the solution and projects with Visual Studio.

Thanks!
-Sean

Answer (score 40):

You'll need to specify any solution folders in the Visual Studio solution file, and replace any "." in the project name with "_":

`msbuild SomeSolution.sln /p:Configuration:CustomDebug;Platform=OurPlatform /t:Folder\Project_Name`

For example, if you have a project in the solution folder "Deploy" named "MyApplication.Deployment.csproj", you'll need

`msbuild SomeSolution.sln /p:Configuration:CustomDebug;Platform=OurPlatform /t:Deploy\MyApplication_Deployment`

Incidentially this is a *solution folder*, as displayed in Visual Studio, *not* a file system folder: those are ignored.

Comment: /t:Deploy\MyApplication_Deployment works for me, but how define the target for building this project.. /t:Deploy\MyApplication_Deployment:Rebuild works but no custom targets..

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx you might need to use `;`

Comment: The key for me was the "_" for "." piece; I can't see anywhere in the MS docs that this is needed for specifying a specific project within a solution. Was pulling my hair out until I came across this solution.

Comment: I also had to replace '(' and ')' with '_' in the folder name (GYP generated projects). I guess all the special characters are replaced with underscore.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following commandline for building your project using msbuild from commandline

```
msbuild Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x86 /t:ProjectName:Rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

Invoke MSBuild on the project file instead of the solution file (ref.`msbuild /?`)

```
msbuild SomeDotNetProject\SomeDotNetProject.csproj /p:Configuration:CustomDebug;Platform=OurPlatform /nodeReuse:false /maxcpucount:4 /t:Build
```

Comment: That won't work for two reasons:
- We use project references, which don't seem to resolve properly
- We use solution configurations that maps to different combinations of "configurations" and platforms
Just trying (for the heck of), got to where dependencies built, but it failed where it expected the platform/configuration to match.

Comment: This was helpful, except I needed to use an equal sign after "/p:Configuration" so instead of "/p:Configuration:CustomDebug" something like "/p:Configuration=CustomDebug", this fixed an error I was getting.